# Having trouble in creating a new Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

i tried to create a new angular project but i am having this error 
just to know i have the latest version of angular and for node JS i am using the 12.16.2.

---

- ng new project

---

the output :

---

/ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.1: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to fsevents 2 with massive improvements.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...er","version":"2.4.9"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-21T17_57_57_578Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAydG.png)

Comment: Please post a full output of the error log and also provide the code you entered to produce the error.

Comment: are you using jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes cleaning the cache helps:  [Update Angular after clearing Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61346688/2976876)

Comment: Already tried it and even tried to use the admin cmd ain't working  :/

Comment: As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like it is a cache error. Reinstalling Angular CLI after clearing the npm cache. The below solution work for me, run below 3 commands one by one

- npm install chokidar
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

**Issue**
[image]

**Resolution screen short:**
[image]