# How do I get rid of this angular error message

Tags: node.js, json, angular, npm, cmd

While trying to create a new project with angular, I used the command `ng new my-dream-app` in command prompt and I receiver the following error message:

```
 Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.1: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to fsevents 2 with massive improvements.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...t-config-prettier":"^'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Izormen Onotieose\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-21T14_21_50_827Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
```

Pls how do I go about this?

Comment: Can you show us your log file `C:\Users\Izormen Onotieose\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-21T14_21_50_827Z-debug.log` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is a cache error. Try this:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning the cache and reinstalling global Angular CLI.

Open CMD as administrator and run

```sh
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```