# Angular 9 Issue: Unable to run the initial application

Tags: angular, angular9, darwin, fsevents, microtime

**Can someone help me to resolve the following issue?**

I am following the https://v8.angular.io/guide/setup-local#prerequisites document to set up the initial application on my windows machine but facing an issue.

**OS:** Windows 10, 64-bit

**Issue:** **npm install** is failing.

**Response:**
CREATE my-app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
- Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mark":"~1","microtime'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! .\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-05T03_21_42_870Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.

The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue until this morning.
please try installing / updating chokidar to version 3.+

> npm install chokidar

Also, try reinstalling Angular CLI after clearing npm cache

> npm cache clean --force
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Thanks Aditya, little progress it there with a new bug now while running the app.

ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at resolveAlias (D:\Test N Learn\Angular\Angular9\angular-role-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:34043:37)

Comment: try running this -> npm update @angular/cli @angular/core

Comment: Really a working solution for me. Thanks a lot Aditya.

Comment: Welcome @rockey91

Answer (score 1):

> Below solution work for me:

It looks like it is a cache error. Reinstalling Angular CLI after clearing npm cache

Click here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924964/10181929

[image]

Comment: Please either explain why that answer is helpful though the question is different flag as duplicate. Do not just link/copy a different StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your suggestion and added small intro above as well. I don't want to give again the same answer here, that's why I share my answer URL here.